# Angular i18n extract clobbers previous changes?

Tags: angular, internationalization, workflow, text-extraction

I'm trying to see if there's a native workflow in Angular CLI for

1. Extracting Translations
2. Sending and Receiving translations back
3. Updating Code with new copy blocks
4. Extracting again // point of failure
5. Sending and Recieving translations back

If I extract the new translations will clobber the old.  Is there a process to reconcile two extractions?  Or a plan to? Is it expected for the dev team to roll their own? Just looking for clarity

HTML:

```
<h1>Hello i18n!</h1>
```

1. Extract translations:

   ```
   <body>
     <trans-unit id="introductionHeader" datatype="html">
       <source>Hello i18n!</source>
       <context-group purpose="location">
         <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/app.component.ts</context>
         <context context-type="linenumber">1</context>
       </context-group>
       <note priority="1" from="description">An introduction header for this sample</note>
       <note priority="1" from="meaning">site header</note>
     </trans-unit>
   </body>
   ```
2. Sending and Receiving translations back

   ```
        <body>
         <trans-unit id="introductionHeader" datatype="html">
           <source>Hello i18n!</source>
           <target>HERRO i18n!</target>
           <context-group purpose="location">
             <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/app.component.ts</context>
             <context context-type="linenumber">1</context>
           </context-group>
           <note priority="1" from="description">An introduction header for this sample</note>
           <note priority="1" from="meaning">site header</note>
         </trans-unit>
       </body>
   ```
3. Update Code with new copy blocks

   `<h1>Hello i18n!</h1>`
   `<h1>Goodbye i18n!</h1>`
4. Extract again will remove the `<target>translated content</target>`

And therefore everything will have to be retranslated.

Is there a workflow for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this tool:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-i18nsupport

I think it's what u're looking for.

Comment: could you please provide some context, as in an explanation of how to implement this?